# Recover SVN after data loss

Tags: svn, backup

My coworker and I have been using SVN for our project. We've been working in the same branch for the past few weeks, committing and merging files as necessary. Three days ago, our SVN server died and we lost all our data. I was (stupidly) not making regular backups to a separate server, so the best backup I have is 200 revisions behind where we are.

Is there any way to get our checked-out copies all merged correctly and back into SVN?

I don't care about the revision history. I just want to make sure that all the code that I have is properly merged with the code that my coworker has.

Comment: I'm not trolling - you should move to git.  This type of problem doesn't exist and you don't need to regular backups, since each person working on the project has already backed up the project for you.

Comment: I've heard that so often that I'm sure you're right. I just never got around to it. This incident might be the final straw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step i would do is to perform the comand `svn diff` on the computer holding the older working copy revision. It creates a diff file containing the changes of the current version regarding the last check-out.

Second copy the checked out structure on the computer which has the newer revision checked-out and disconnect it from the crashed repository (remove all the .svn meta data directories). Afterwards check it in into the new clean repository.

Now take the diff file created previously and apply it on the just checked-in working copy. Hopefully you will only get some smaller conflicts which can be solved easily by you or your coworker. If all problems are solved check it in.

Note: This instructions target in creating a fully new repository. The outdated backup has not been considered.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand step 1. Right now, I have set up a local SVN server on my machine (svn.local) that has the repository at revision 500. I also have a working copy that I checked out from the now-dead server (svn.oldserver.com) that is at revision 700. When try to do a diff from the repo (rev 500) to the working copy (rev 700), it tells me that it cannot connect to svn.oldserver.com.

Comment: AFAIK svn diff only shows the differences in your local working space - it does not need to access the repository on the server. Therefore it should still work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still lost. Let's say I have two directories, "olddir" and "newdir". "olddir" contains a checked-out copy of the old (pre-data-loss) repository. "newdir" contains the working copy that I'd like to merge in, but does not have access to it's svn repo (because the server no longer exists). Can you give me the svn command that I need to run to get the correct diff? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't realize that you could just run svn diff and it would give you the changes since last commit. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
svnadmin recover <svn path>
```

OR

```
svnadmin verify <svn path>
```