# Cloudforge svn server sunsetted - can I recover repo from .svn folder?

Tags: git, svn, migration, tortoisesvn

As the title says, I have a few repos going back years on Cloudforge and have been meaning to move to git. Finally got around to it tonight, and Cloudforge closed on 1 October. Tears.

I read that svn is not distributed like git, so does this mean the local `.svn` folder doesn't contain the necessary info to recover/convert to git? I have years of commit history I would like to maintain if possible.

Steps taken so far:

- Installed TortoiseSVN, with command line tool
- Google foo, including [this](https://wiki.loopback.org/display/KB/Straight-forward+svn+to+git+migration+with+TortoiseSVN+or+Linux+git), [this](https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/migrate-from-svn-to-git/), and [this](https://dominikdorn.com/2016/05/how-to-recover-a-google-code-svn-project-and-migrate-to-github/).
- SO research shows questions related to migration once the SVN server is running, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832161/recover-svn-after-data-loss).

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this mean the local .svn folder doesn't contain the necessary info to recover/convert to git?

Yes. `/svn` contain only Pristine Copy of sources for currently checkout-ed revision in your WC in order to perform *some operations* with local-only data: diff|undo changes etc.

You have to contact Cloudforge and ask for help with getting your repo dump in ordr to have full history of project: with SVN WC you have only one version (which is "your WC state")